# How to get the textarea value in a div element?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the text typed in `textarea` with id `text` in the div element `typed`, how can i?

**head**

```
<script> 
function field()
{ 

var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
if (txt.length > 0){
document.getElementById("typed").value = txt; 

}

}

</script>
```

**body**

```
<input type="text" id="text"></input>

<br>
<b> You Typed : <div id="typed"></div> </b>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="field()">
```

Comment: Where is the `textarea` ?

Comment: Right now you are just assigning the value back to the input. Do yu mean `document.getElementById("typed").textContent = txt;` instead?

Comment: Sorry! it was `typed`, i'm mistakken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.value` is for input elements. To put something in a `DIV`, use `.innerText`:

```
document.getElementById("typed").innerText = txt;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4PuZX/2/) with `<input>`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4PuZX/3/) with `<textarea>`

Comment: If they're typing HTML in the textarea, and you want to render it, use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`.

Comment: No, it's just a simple textarea & the only problem is, value comes with a break tag.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. I don't see a break tag in my fiddle demos.

Comment: I mean text should be in the same line as "You Typed".

Comment: Use CSS to make the DIV inline instead of block. Or use `<span>` instead of `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the function like the following

```
function field()
{ 
  var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
  if (txt.length > 0)
  {
     document.getElementById("typed").innerText= txt; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can with this :

```
    <html>
<head>

<script> 
function field()
{ 

var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
if (txt.length > 0){
document.getElementById("typed").innerText = txt; 
console.log(txt);
}

}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="text"></input>

<br>
<b> You Typed : <div id="typed"></div> </b>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="field()">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementById("typed").innerHtml = document.getElementById("text").value;
```